# What's this cactus with large red and white spines?

Tags: identification, cactus

I just got this cactus with large red and white spines and I'd like to know its species. It looks like a [ferocactus emoryi](http://www.cactus-art.biz/schede/FEROCACTUS/Ferocactus_emoryi/Ferocactus_emoryi/Ferocactus_emoryi.htm) except the spines are not hooked. But it could be something else as there are so many different species of ferocactus. Some species of gymnocalycium also look like this.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close with Ferocactus emoryi, but it's a different variety - I think it's a young Ferocactus recurvus, also known as Bisnaga recurva, image in the link below, scroll down a bit to find it

http://www.llifle.com/Encyclopedia/CACTI/Family/Cactaceae/4295/Bisnaga_recurva